# Arrays de objetos

Tags: java

tengo una duda respecto a los arrays de objetos, por ejemplo, ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para poder llamar a algún método por medio del array de objetos?

Yo tengo el siguiente método que esta en otra clase

```
public void calcular_Bono()
{
    if(Retardos<=2)
    {
       Bono=Sueldo*0.10;
       Sueldo+=Bono;
       Total_Con_Bono++;
    }
}
```

entonces al crear yo otra clase para poder crear el array de objetos y una vez ya leídos los datos como puedo hacer para poder llamar al método Calcular_Bono en esta clase

```
package Nomina;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class clsPrincipal {


public static void main(String[] args) {
     int num_empleados;
    Scanner Entrada= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingresa el numero de empelados a registrar: ");
    num_empleados=Entrada.nextInt();
    clsNomina vecEm[]= new clsNomina[num_empleados];
    for(int i=0; i<num_empleados; i++)
    {
       System.out.println("Empleado "+(i+1));
       System.out.println("Ingresa el nombre del empleado: ");
       String Nombre= Entrada.next();
       
       Entrada.nextLine();
        
       System.out.println("Ingresa tu sueldo: ");
       double Sueldo=Entrada.nextDouble();
       
       System.out.println("Ingresa la cantidad de retardos en esta semana: ");
       int Retardos=Entrada.nextInt();
       
       System.out.println("=====================");
       vecEm[i]=new clsNomina(Nombre,Sueldo,Retardos,num_empleados);
    }
}

}
```

Agradecería que me pudieran ayudar.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara y además usas una convención de nombre demasiado confusa. Si tú estás recorriendo un array de objetos dentro de un bucle por ejemplo, y cada elemento se llama `unObjeto`, tú puedes invocar a `cualquierMetodo` de `unObjeto` con una llamada como esta: `unObjeto.cualquierMetodo()`.

Comment: @Enrique una duda y si quiero mandar a llamar un método para todas las posiciones del arreglo y a la vez ese método este acumulando una equis cantidad como puedo acceder a esa cantidad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para llamar a métodos del objeto de tu array tienes que indicar que posición del array quieres que llame al método.
Por ejemplo: `vecEm[0].calcular_Bono();`
y bueno si es dentro de un for para llamar al método por cada posición:

```
for(int i=0; i<num_empleados; i++)
vecEm[i].calcularBono();
```